# Can you pass a custom variable into Google Analytics event tracking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, google-analytics, jquery-events

In Google Analytics, you can track events like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#home .post', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Home', 'click', 'Posts', '4');
});
```

What I'm wondering is if I can, instead of '4', pass a variable like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#home .post', function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var indexStr = '' + index;
    ga('send', 'event', 'Home', 'click', 'Posts', indexStr);
});
```

If it does, I'm also wondering if it is necessary for me to convert it to string.

Comment: How would I confirm it?

Comment: In your browser - you can use the network tab of your browser to inspect the `https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect` request generated by google analytics... then check for the param name `ev`

Comment: In GA go to the real-time dashboard -> events. Run it in console and you'll see it pop up there immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes you can pass a custom variable in Google Analytics.